# root - ERROR - post - 46 - Record creation failed: (1062, "Duplicate entry '23SNS0002' for key '' ")

Tags: django, save, auto-increment, prefix, userid

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Employee(models.Model):
emp_id = models.CharField(editable=False,unique=True,max_length=10,default=None)

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    if not self.emp_id:
       prefix2 = format(timezone.now().strftime('%y'))+'SNS'
       prev_instances = self.__class__.objects.filter(emp_id__contains=prefix2)
       if prev_instances.exists():
          last_instance_id = prev_instances.last().emp_id[-4:]
          self.emp_id = prefix2+'{0:04d}'.format(int(last_instance_id)+1)
          self.email_id
       else:
           self.emp_id =prefix2+'{0:04d}'.format(1)
           self.emp_id
    super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 04, 2023 - 12:37:39
Django version 4.1, using settings 'CRMSolutions.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[04/Mar/2023 12:37:45] "POST /employee/emp/ HTTP/1.1" 201 418
[04/Mar/2023 12:38:06] "POST /employee/emp/ HTTP/1.1" 201 416
2023-03-04 12:38:20,500 - root - ERROR - post - 46 - employee Record creation failed: (1062, "Duplicate entry '23SNS0002' for key 'employee_employee
.emp_id'")
Internal Server Error: /employee/emp/
2023-03-04 12:38:20,500 - django.request - ERROR - log_response - 241 - Internal Server Error: /employee/emp/
[04/Mar/2023 12:38:20] "POST /employee/emp/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73

i want to generate employee id example: 23SNS0001,23SNSNS0002,23SNS0003.... and so on... as unique and should not form duplicate...emp_id.
above shown my models create duplicate .... even if i set unique = True.
i think i have to change my code in save function that i have used...can help with problem to solve

Comment: Please format your code correctly, it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the second line with "self.emp_id" is a typo:

```
else:
           self.emp_id =prefix2+'{0:04d}'.format(1)
           self.emp_id
```